# ABP EF Core multiple DbContext access in IDomainService throws transaction error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, transactions, dbcontext, aspnetboilerplate

> The specified transaction is not associated with the current connection. Only transactions associated with the current connection may be used.

How do I use multiple DbContext in one transaction?

## Update 1

If I use `ExistingConnection`,
then all the DbContext will use the same connection string.

Did I add multiple DbContext in the wrong way?

In EntityFrameworkModule:

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    var configuration = AppConfigurations.Get(WebContentDirectoryFinder.CalculateContentRootFolder());

    Configuration.Modules.AbpEfCore().AddDbContext<BPDbContext>(options =>
    {
        if (options.ExistingConnection != null)
        {
            options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(options.ExistingConnection);
        }
        else
        {
            options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(ABPCoreConsts.BPConnectionStringName));
        }

        //options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(
        //    configuration.GetConnectionString(ABPCoreConsts.BPConnectionStringName));
    });

    Configuration.Modules.AbpEfCore().AddDbContext<EPlusDBConext>(options =>
    {
        if (options.ExistingConnection != null)
        {
            options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(options.ExistingConnection);
        }
        else
        {
            options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(ABPCoreConsts.EECPlusConnectionStringName));
        }

        //options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(
        //    configuration.GetConnectionString(ABPCoreConsts.EECPlusConnectionStringName));
    });

    Configuration.Modules.AbpEfCore().AddDbContext<ProjectManageDbContext>(options =>
    {
        if (options.ExistingConnection != null)
        {
            options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(options.ExistingConnection);
        }
        else
        {
            options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(ABPCoreConsts.PMConnectionStringName));
        }

        //options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(
        //    configuration.GetConnectionString(ABPCoreConsts.PMConnectionStringName));
    });

    RegisterGenericRepositories();
}
```

## Update 2

I got it to work by implementing `IConnectionStringResolver` for custom connections:

```
public class MyDBConnectionStringResolver : DefaultConnectionStringResolver
{
    public override string GetNameOrConnectionString(ConnectionStringResolveArgs args)
    {
        var configuration = AppConfigurations.Get(WebContentDirectoryFinder.CalculateContentRootFolder());

        switch (args["DbContextType"].ToString())
        {
            case "ABPCore.EPlusDBConext":
                return configuration.GetConnectionString(ABPCoreConsts.EECPlusConnectionStringName);
            case "ABPCore.BPDbContext":
                return configuration.GetConnectionString(ABPCoreConsts.BPConnectionStringName);
            case "ABPCore.ProjectManageDbContext":
                return configuration.GetConnectionString(ABPCoreConsts.PMConnectionStringName);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace service in EntityFrameworkModule's `PreInitialize` method:

```
Configuration.ReplaceService<IConnectionStringResolver, MyDbConnectionStringResolver>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

Comment: it's work now ,code in  https://github.com/BivoZeou/ABPCore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in `*DbContextConfigurer.cs`:

```
public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<*DbContext> builder, DbConnection connection)
{
    builder.UseSqlServer(connection);
}
```

Change this in `*EntityFrameworkModule.cs`:

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    if (!SkipDbContextRegistration)
    {
        Configuration.Modules.AbpEfCore().AddDbContext<*DbContext>(options =>
        {
            if (options.ExistingConnection != null)
            {
                options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(options.ExistingConnection);
            }
            else
            {
                options.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(options.ConnectionString);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/commit/da522e76ca2ecefdb7670f009f78575c5b97b4a0

---

## Important

If each `DbContext` has its own connection string, you need to implement `IConnectionStringResolver` as explained [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/1834#issuecomment-326041970) and replace the service:

```
Configuration.ReplaceService<IConnectionStringResolver, MyConnectionStringResolver>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

Comment: if i usd  existing connection ,the multiple dbcontext will use one connectionstring , it will throw  SqlException: Invalid object name 'tablexxx', is that i'm add multiple dbcontext in wrong way?  i add dbcontext at EntityFrameworkModule, PreInitialize

Comment: i'm sure  when i debug ,existing connection is same, my code in https://github.com/BivoZeou/ABPCore here you can see

Comment: Can you implement and replace `IConnectionStringResolver` as explained [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/1834#issuecomment-326041970)? You have the same issue as [this](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2325).

Comment: i'm impl IConnectionStringResolver  ,it's work!, thanks a lot !

Comment: You're welcome! I'll update my answer with that so others can benefit :)